# Delete record by using toast confirm in primeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I use primeNG in my angular project, in the table every row have a delete button to show confirm box(toast) then I need to delete the record after user click confirm button in the box,

my apologies because I'm really very new to this, so please forgive me for what some may seem a very basic question.

in my HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="showConfirm(rowData.id)"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span</button>

<p-toast position="center" key="c" (onClose)="onReject()" [modal]="true" [baseZIndex]="5000">
    <ng-template let-message pTemplate="message">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <i class="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
            <h3>{{message.summary}}</h3>
            <p>{{message.detail}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <button type="button" pButton (click)="onConfirm()" label="confirm" class="ui-button-success"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <button type="button" pButton (click)="onReject()" label="calcel" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-toast>`enter code here`
```

and this my code in **compontent.ts**

```
... 
showConfirm(id:Clients) {
    this.messageService.add({key: 'c', sticky: true, severity:'warn', summary:'!تأكيد الحذف', detail:'هل تريد حذف هذا العميل؟'});}

onConfirm() {
// Here i need to delete the same record 

}
onReject() {
    this.messageService.clear('c');
}
```

my **service.ts**

```
clientsUrl="http://localhost:4200/api/clints"

deleteClient(id){
    return this.http.delete(this.clientsUrl + "/" + id)

      }
```

so How to pass the same parameter to onConfirm method?

or What the best way to handle it?

Comment: you need to show a toast after the user details were deleted and you don't know how to pass the parameter to the "onConfirm" method, am i correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, actually I want to show a toast when user click the delete button `<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="showConfirm(rowData.id)"> ...` then if click confirm button delete the same record, so my proplem how to pass the parameter(id) to `onConfirm()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this, in your on confirm method

```
 `service.deleteClient(id).then((response: any) => {
         if (response.responseStatusId === 1) {
               //response.responseStatusId can be different
               //your toast method
                 }
                }`
```

and in your Service:

```
`deleteClient(id){
  const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   return this.http.delete(this.clientsUrl + "/" + id).then((data: any) => {
     if (data) {
       resolve(data);
         } else{
            reject({});
            }
            }).catch((error:any) => {
               reject(error);
                });}
                 return promise;
                 }`
```

Comment: 1-can I make it in Observable not promise? 2- the same problem how to pass the same parameter(id) to `onConfirm()` method.

Comment: so you are asking how to pass the parameter from HTML to "onConfirm" method

Comment: of course yes you can make it observable but in this case, I prefer promise

Comment: I asking How I use the same parameter in tow method `showConfirm(id)` and `onConfirm(id)` the first one to show box and second fo delete the same selected row. finally why you prefer promise in this case?

Comment: you can do this when you click on "showConfirm(rowData.id)" your passing the id to "showConfirm(id:Clients)", in this method you can define a variable called clientId and store the clients ID. and when you call the "onConfirm()" method you can use that "clientId" to pass to the service. 

hope you got the answer!

Comment: exactly, please forgive me for the next stupid question but I really don't know: the definition of the variable will be `clientId: Clients[ ] = id;` am I correct? as per my _clinet.model.ts_ `export class Clients {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    phone:string;
    address:string;
    type:string;
    account:number;
    nots:string;}`

Comment: 1st define a variable private clientId;

and your passing rowData.id via this "showConfirm(rowData.id)" and in your method you are getting it "showConfirm(id:Clients)", change it like showConfirm(id).
and inside your method "this.clientId =id".

rather than passing "rowData.id" you can also pass an $event
hope you get it. if my answers and comments are helpful upvotes are apreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203315/discussion-between-mohamed-elkast-and-hiras-haris).